# Using Visual Studio testing tools with jquery web pages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, qunit

I am trying to find the best method to test an ASP web application that uses JQuery to render the web pages.  I have been looking using Qunit, but I am not well versed in Javascript.  Is there an easier path to go down?

Answer (score 0):

We use Selenium RC to test the rendered pages.

http://seleniumhq.org/

You can reference the Selenium engine from your normal unit tests.